# Layer time extent calculating problem while table joining with layer using ArcObjects C# .NET

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, timeslider

I have added a layer in the ArcMap. I want to see the different values of the items of this layer using the "Time Slider". For this, I have prepared a table that contains a field named DateTime and its type is Date. After completing data preparation I have joined the table with the layer using ArcObjects C# .NET AddJoin tool. After this, when I calculate the layer time extent. It set start time and end time the same as the start time.

[image]
[image]

If I remove join from the layer or skip the join operation using ArcObjects and join the table with the layer manually in ArcMap then it works fine.

[image]
AddJoin Tool Code:

```c#
public AddJoin(string inputLayerName, string inputTableField, string tableToBeJoinedPath, string toBeJoinedField)
    {
        _inputLayerName = inputLayerName;
        _inputTableField = inputTableField;
        _tableToBeJoinedPath = tableToBeJoinedPath;
        _toBeJoinedField = toBeJoinedField;
    }

    public IGpResult Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            var addJoinTool = InitTool();
            var result = _gp.Execute(addJoinTool, null) as IGeoProcessorResult;
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.AddJoin InitTool()
    {
        _gp = new Geoprocessor { OverwriteOutput = true, AddOutputsToMap = false };
        var addJoin = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.AddJoin()
        {
            in_layer_or_view = _inputLayerName,
            in_field = _inputTableField,
            join_table = _tableToBeJoinedPath.Replace(@"\", @"\\"),
            join_field = _toBeJoinedField,
            join_type = "KEEP_ALL",
        };
        _gp.OverwriteOutput = true;
        return addJoin;
    }        
}
```

How can I join it using ArcObjects and make it workable?

Comment: I don't see any C# code, what AddJoin tool are you referring to? Is the field a datetime field or a string field with date text?

Comment: Sorry I haven't added C# code.

Comment: The field is DateTime type, not a string type.

Comment: Please show the code where you set the time properties of the layer.

Comment: @Hornbydd, I didn't set the time properties of the layer in code. I want also to do that.
I did it manually by using the layer properties window.

Comment: This isn't ArcObjects code, it's a C# implementation of a geoprocessing tool. I think the interface you're after is IMapTimeDisplay https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IMapTimeDisplay_Interface/001200000m79000000/ implemented by Map and ITimeData https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000r97000000 implemented by IFeatureLayer but how to get there from where you are is not a trivial matter and requires *real* ArcObjects code.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, I already have said in comment that I didn't set the time interval,
MapTimeExtent by code. I did it manually. I only ran the AddJoin tool for completing the data process purpose and faced the situation that I mentioned. I shared the code where the ArcObjects code is implemented in just a C# class wrapper.

Comment: I think you may be confused with what ArcObjects is and isn't, arcpy *isn't* ArcObjects even if it comes in a C# wrapper, ArcObjects derive from ArcMap.Application and are implemented with interfaces from ArcObjects https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/ArcObjects_namespaces/000800000002000000/ there is a massive gulf between where you are in the supplied code and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, Thank you for your reply. Now I am a bit more confused. I didn't use Arcpy. Could you please confirm me wheather https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0054000000nn000000 it is ArcObject Or not?
I have used this in my code.

Comment: That is from the ArcObjects help but is a standalone geoprocessor interface, if you approach from the ArcObjects component tree it's a quick way to do some trivial tasks however calling it as isolated code is the same as running the arcpy version of the add join tool, I've done this in ArcObjects and it takes about twice as much code as you have there to get the IStandaloneTable and IDisplayRelationshipClass together to join, what code you have is nearly inconsequential, what we would need to see is how this relates to an ILayer that implements FeatureLayer.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of **AddJoin** geoprocessor tool, I do it with **IDisplayRelationshipClass** and now it's working fine.
Code developed for this:

```c#
public void Join(IFeatureLayer featureLayer, string foreignKeyField, ITable table, string primaryKeyField)
    {
        try
        {                
           using (var comReleaser = new ComReleaser())
           {
               var memRelClassFactoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriGeodatabase.MemoryRelationshipClassFactory");
               var memRelClassFactory = (IMemoryRelationshipClassFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(memRelClassFactoryType);
               var tableObjectClass = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IObjectClass)table;
               var geoFeatureLayer = featureLayer as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IGeoFeatureLayer;
               var pRelClass = memRelClassFactory.Open(table.Name + "To" + featureLayer.Name, tableObjectClass, primaryKeyField, geoFeatureLayer.DisplayFeatureClass, foreignKeyField, "ForwardPath", "BackwardPath",
                        esriRelCardinality.esriRelCardinalityOneToMany);
               comReleaser.ManageLifetime(pRelClass);
               var displayRelationshipClass = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IDisplayRelationshipClass)geoFeatureLayer;
               comReleaser.ManageLifetime(displayRelationshipClass);
                    displayRelationshipClass.DisplayRelationshipClass(pRelClass, esriJoinType.esriLeftOuterJoin);
           }
        }
        catch (COMException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```